# Is it possible to get measure value from facts table for a parent member of a hierarchy ignoring the children's values?

Tags: ssas, parent-child, olap-cube, dimensional-modeling

We are creating a Financial OLAP cube with a parent-child hierarchy for the financial entities. The facts table contains measures for both the parent and child entities and the parent's value is not equal to the total of its children's values. For example, in facts table we have:

```
+----------+----------+
| EntityID | NetSales |
+----------+----------+
| Europe   |    15000 |
| Spain    |     3500 |
| France   |     8000 |
| Italy    |     5000 |
+----------+----------+
```

Spain, France and Italy are children of Europe but Europe's total Net Sales is not the total of Spain + France + Italy due to eliminations done when sales are done between those children (Spain to France, etc.).

We need to create a dimension in the cube that will show the correct total of the parent Entity based on it's value on the facts table and not the aggregation of its children.

Is it possible to configure SSAS model or add custom MDX code to "overwrite" the value of the parent entity with the facts value for that entity and disregard the total of its children?

Note: there are 6 levels in the hierarchy, each parent level should take its own facts value for the measure and not the total of its children.

Expected result in cube would be:

```
+----------+----------+
| Entity   | NetSales |
+----------+----------+
| Europe   |    15000 |
|   Spain  |     3500 |
|   France |     8000 |
|   Italy  |     5000 |
+----------+----------+
```

Actual result in cube with normal aggregation:

```
+----------+----------+
| Entity   | NetSales |
+----------+----------+
| Europe   |    16500 |
|   Spain  |     3500 |
|   France |     8000 |
|   Italy  |     5000 |
+----------+----------+
```

Any advice will be highly appreciated.